# ddwrt wireless client not getting wan ip

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I want to use a router in order to share my smarphone's internet with a bunch of wired LAN devices.

My router is a tplink tl-wr841nd v11 running ddwrt v3.0

I found that I have to use wireless client mode. I put my phone's hotspot details in the wireless basic settings:

wireless mode: client
wireless network mode: mixed
channel width: full
ssid: myhotspotssid

and under wireless security

security mode: wpa
network authentication: wpa2 personal
wpa algorithms: aes
wpa shared key: mypassword

then under setup > wan connection type I put automatic config dhcp

I changed the routers local ip eventhough it isnt connected to another router and my phones address pool starts at 192.168.43.2, just for the sake of it.

I save and reboot but the router is not connecting to my phone.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the problem was in my phone. I logged into the router via ssh and issued `site_survey` which revealed that the router did not see my hotspot. I used another phone and everything worked as expected.